# How to see if a the first varible of a List with custom class contain somthing?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, unity-game-engine

So if it is a dictionary, I can check if the Key or Value contains something on its own.
But if you have a list with a custom class. Things are different. In the script below, the dictionary is working properly since the wayspotAnchors.ID type is called Guid, and the key of a dictionary is Guid, so in Dictionary, it only compares if it contains the ID by using ContainKey.
However, when I use a List with a custom class. In the Custom class, it has more than one variable which allows my list to store many things.

The problem is when I compare the wayspotAnchors.ID with the List, it compares to everything that is stored in the list which creates an error because the second variable type in the custom list is not matching with the Guid only the first variable is. But there is no way to only compare the first variable of a custom List as Dictionary does.

```
  private void CreateAnchorGameObjects(IWayspotAnchor[] wayspotAnchors)
    {
        foreach (var wayspotAnchor in wayspotAnchors)
        {
            if (gameData_List.my_second_game_list.)
            {
                
            }
            if (_wayspotAnchorGameObjects.ContainsKey(wayspotAnchor.ID))
            {
                Debug.Log("working");
            continue;
            }
```

The custom class

```
public class MySecondGameList
{
    public Guid guid;
    public string readable_guid;
    public GameObject anchor_gameobject;
}
```

List of the custom class

```
public class GameData_List : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    public List<MySecondGameList> my_second_game_list;
}
```

The error
[image]

Comment: You do  not need to list.  You can enumerate through a dictionary just like enumerating through the list to get every item (or a set of keys).

Comment: How many items to you expect `my_second_game_list` and `wayspotAnchors` to have typically? Will it be in the tens, hundreds, thousands, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list applying the [Any IEnumerable Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0). The Any method requires a lambda expression that returns a boolean value. If, during the enumeration, any lambda expression applied to the enumerated element, returns true, then the Any method stops the enumeration and returns true to your code

```
var searchedGuid = wayspotAnchor.ID;
if (gameData_List.my_second_game_list.Any(x => x.guid == searchedGuid))
{
    // true

}
```

Comment: worth mentioning that this is in another namespace => `using System.Linq;`

Comment: foreach (var id in myloadinglist)
                {
                    if (GameData_List.my_loading_list.Any(x => x.guid == id.guid))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Matching!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                        continue;
                    }    GameData_List.my_loading_list.AddRange(myloadinglist);
                    Debug.Log("It is loading");
                }    I do it this way in the end to prevent it load twice, the problem is both of the variable that I want is all in the custom class which I need to go through the whole list for both of them.

Comment: Yes, I have just accepted it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In stead of Contains you can use the Linq extension Any like this:

```
if (_wayspotAnchorGameObjects.Any(anchor => anchor.guid == wayspotAnchor.ID))
```

Comment: worth mentioning that this is in another namespace => `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `Any()` might be way slower compared to `ContainsKey()` depending on the length of `_wayspotAnchorGameObjects`.